# manual solutions to graduate textbooks

Tags: textbooks

Where can I find manual solution for textbooks like Advanced Linear Algebra by Rotman or Introduction to Smooth manifolds by Lee? any help would be appreciated

Comment: Here's the solutions for Lee Smooth Manifolds: [Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds Solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750163/lee-introduction-to-smooth-manifolds-solutions) (just kidding. it's a maths se question about it, and then lee hself replies saying there's none.)

Comment: seriously though look up 'SOLUTIONS TO INTRODUCTION TO SMOOTH MANIFOLDS BY JOHN M. LEE, 2012, SPRINGER' by ernest yeung

Comment: Steven Roman’s Advanced Linear Algebra. try here: https://wj32.org/wp/mathematics/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a question about math education.

Comment: why don't you ask this on math stackexchange instead of math educators stackexchange?

Comment: I am sorry I was unfamiliar and still I am

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, publishers will sell (or send for free) solutions manuals to problems in their textbooks if you are a teacher that is using the textbook in class.  They might ask for proof of this (for example, a class webpage listing the textbook as the reference with your name as the teacher).  (This happened to me a few decades ago---a probability textbook by Peebles from McGraw-Hill.)  Visit the publisher's website or contact the publisher directly to find out if they have such a manual available.

Of course, some authors do not create solutions manuals for their textbooks.  There is a chance that someone else has created such a manual (for example, I know a faculty member who did this).  You might find these by using an internet search engine.  But be careful in this case because you would not be sure if the solutions are correct.

Comment: [How do you explain to someone that the answers given in math.stackexchange.com are correct (whenever they are)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16518/how-do-you-know-that-their-answers-are-correct)

Answer (score -2):

I assume you mean roman not rotman.

1. lee smooth manifolds. look up 'SOLUTIONS TO INTRODUCTION TO SMOOTH MANIFOLDS BY JOHN M. LEE, 2012, SPRINGER' by ernest yeung
2. lee smooth manifolds again. try here: https://wj32.org/wp/mathematics/
3. Steven Roman’s Advanced Linear Algebra. try here: https://wj32.org/wp/mathematics/